# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode' in SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

I have scraped tweets using snscrape library in python. I was willing to get the sentiment for each of the tweets. In order to do That, I have used SentimentIntensityAnalyzer() from nltk and the following error popped up.

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I went back to the dataset resulted from the scraping and it shows the type of the Text column of the dataset as the following

```
type(data['Text'])
Out[42]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

I tried to change the data type and do other operations but the results were not positive. What approach should I take?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide enough code for us to replicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing data['Text'] through pandas.apply() function and then using SentimentIntensityAnalyzer() does the trick. The fact is the function is not capable of handling the series object. Passing one by one element to SentimentIntensityAnalyzer() using a looping function does the job in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your library returns a pandas dataframe object with your data. (See: https://pandas.pydata.org/). With the syntax dataframe['string'] you get back a pandas series-object which is a subset of a dataframe object (a column to be exact).

In your example you get the contents of the dataframe "data". Specifically, the contents of the column "Text".

This pandas series object does not have the method "encode" depending on what you want to do, you may have to encode every item of that series object. e.g.:

```
for value in data['Text']:
  print(value.encode())
```